# Using the Shortcut to Redirect in a Controller

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have the following UrlMapping

```
"404"(controller:"home", action:"index")
```

I can redirect in a Controller to the 404 page by using:

```
redirect controller:"home", action:"index"
```

Is there a way to use the mapping in the redirect instead of writing the controller and action, i.e. something like `redirect("404")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Grails 2.3, redirect can be done in `UrlMappings` as below:

```
"/someAction"(redirect : [controller: 'home', action: 'index'])
```

Refer this for [alternative ways](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#redirectMappings).

UPDATE:
In order to use the mapping from controller a better alternative would be to use namedMappings:

```
// UrlMappings
static mappings = {
    name handle404: "404" {
        controller = 'home'
        action = 'index'
    }
}

//controller
redirect(mapping: 'handle404')
```

Comment: I want to redirect in a controller not in a UrlMapping.

Comment: You can try using named mappings as shown in the update above.